# jQuery: Prepending and appending <p> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a an element which I am cloning on page load:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#linked_product_data").prepend($(".parent").clone());
        $(".parent").prepend($("<p>"));
        $(".parent").append($("</p>"));
        $(".parent").append($("<hr>"));     
        $(".parent").prepend($("<p>Grouped Product:</p>"));         
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I'm attempting to wrap this cloned element in `<p>` tags, as you can see in the code. However when I view the source I find that the page has actually been prepended and appended with matching pairs of `<p>` tags, does anyone know of a solution to this?

The output is as below:

```
<div class="bfi-parent">
    <p>Grouped Product:</p>
    <p></p>
    Test |
    <a href="h#"> Manage</a>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <p></p>
        <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you want to wrap the `.parent` element in `<p></p>` tag.. Am I correct?

Comment: When appending a newly-created element using jQuery, there is no need to append the closing tag as well. You're appending an HTML *element* not a bare string. Also, hard to tell from your code without seeing the HTML, but, have you considered using `wrap()` instead?

Comment: When you append some <p> element, the browser may correct you by adding the other. Dont prepend only <p>, better to use $(blabla).html('<p>' + $(blabla).html() + <'/p'>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description, what you are trying is actually to wrap the clone so

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $clone = $(".parent").clone().prependTo('#linked_product_data');
    $clone.wrap("<p />").append("<hr />");
    $clone.prepend("<p>Grouped Product:</p>");
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```css
#linked_product_data {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
#linked_product_data > p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="parent">some content</span>
<div id="linked_product_data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be:

```
(function($) {
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#linked_product_data").prepend($(".parent").clone());
            $( ".parent" ).wrap( "<p></p>" );
            $(".parent").append($("<hr>"));     
            $(".parent").prepend($("<p>Grouped Product:</p>"));         
        });
    }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/zx5f5sp6/)

```js
var $test = $('#test'),
  $html;

$html = '<p class="cloned">' + $test.html() + '</p>';
$test.append($html);
```

```css
.cloned {
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x150?text=IMG">
    <br>Quis itaque rem in quos maxime optio dicta!
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do:

```
.prepend("<p>"+$(".parent").clone().toString()+"</p>");
```

i.e. prepend an opening `<p>` tag, then the element, then a closing `</p>` tag

```
$parent = $(".parent").clone().html();
$("#linked_product_data").prepend("<p>"+$parent+"</p>");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just get '[object Object]' displayed on the screen though.

Comment: You are concatening string so `toString()` is called on `$(".parent").clone()`